# Customização layout do JOptionPane

Tags: java, layout

Estou com a seguinte estrutura do meu JOptionPane, com **campos de digitação na horizontal**:

[image: Imagem]

**Como deixar o campos de digitação na vertical?**

Aqui logo abaixo se encontra o código da classe:

```
import javax.swing.*; 

public class JOptionPaneMultiInput {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JTextField fieldNome = new JTextField(5);
      JTextField fieldTelefone = new JTextField(5);
      JTextField fieldEmail = new JTextField(5);
      JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("Digite Nome:"));
      myPanel.add(fieldNome);
      myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // a spacer
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("Digite Telefone:"));
      myPanel.add(fieldTelefone);
      myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // a spacer
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("Digite Email:"));
      myPanel.add(fieldEmail);

      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, 
               "Entrada de valores", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         System.out.println("Nome value: " + fieldNome.getText());
         System.out.println("Telefone value: " + fieldTelefone.getText());
         System.out.println("Email value: " + fieldEmail.getText());
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Pedro, você precisa adicionar um `LayoutManager` no seu `JPanel`. São muitas opções, o `LayoutManager` ideal vai depender de facilidade e gosto. Dê uma olhada na lista: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html. Recomendo ou o `GridLayout` ou o `SpringLayout`.

Comment: Você está usando alguma IDE?

Comment: @Patrick to usando o eclipse

Comment: Já tentou montar um `JPanel` no prototipador e depois apenas chamá-lo?

Comment: @Patrick com a dica o Wakim acho q consegui....

Comment: Colocar um /n ao final de cada texto também resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda do @Wakim com o uso do GridLayout consegui, como resultado na figura abaixo:

[image: Imagem]

Código adicionado abaixo, resultando nos campos na posição vertical:

```
 GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(0,1);
 myPanel.setLayout(experimentLayout);
```